# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to build a game using Unity WebGL when i run the game offline it has no errors but after uploading it i the the following error "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**".please refer to this [link](http://tunein.freeoda.com/) for error details.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>TuneIN Metronome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico" />
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="template">
    <p class="header"><span>TuneIN Metronome</span>TuneIN</p>
    <div class="template-wrap clear">
      <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="1080px" width="1920px"></canvas>
      <br>
    </div>
    <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  var Module = {
    TOTAL_MEMORY: 268435456,
    errorhandler: null,         // arguments: err, url, line. This function must return 'true' if the error is handled, otherwise 'false'
    compatibilitycheck: null,
    dataUrl: "Release/WebGL.data",
    codeUrl: "Release/WebGL.js",
    memUrl: "Release/WebGL.mem",

  };
</script>
<script src="Release/UnityLoader.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: New Account, upload your files!
Valid indexes: index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml Index.htm Index.html INDEX.HTML INDEX.HTM default.htm default.html home.htm home.html Home.html Home.htm

Attention! File name is case sensitive.

Comment: please check now...was updating the site

Comment: Still the same message